# How do I write my code to dynamically change a part of a form using Select option

Tags: php, forms, select, drop-down-menu, dynamic-forms

I am new to coding, the select option keeps opening in another page but I need it to dynamically change on this same page. I do not know what to do anymore, I have tried switch case, if statements etc.

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="form.php" method="POST">
    <header>
       <p class="Cpage" >Clothing Page</p>
    </header>
         
    <div id="Clothingform" >
    <hr>
    <label for="size">Size</label>
    <input id="size" name="size"  required type="number" />
      
    
    <label for="material">Material</label>
    <input id="material" name="material" required type="text" />
      
    
    <label for="texture">Texture</label>
    <input id="texture" name="texture" required type="text" />

          
          
       <select form="theForm" name="ChangeOption" id="ChangeOption" onchange="if (this.value) 
    window.location.href=this.value">
          <option value="">Change Option</option>
          <option value="lengthoption.php">Length</option>
          <option value="coloroption.php">Color</option>
       </select>
        
    </div>

    <div class="">
       <hr>
       <button class="button" name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
       <button name="cancel" onclick="history.back();" type="reset">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `window.location.href` causes the browser to load another page. What exactly are you wanting to do? Do you mean you want to load the contents of lengthoption.php or coloroption.php into the current page when the user makes the selection? For that you'd need AJAX. Please clarify the precise requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your response, and Yes that's exactly what I want to do but unfortunately I don't know Ajax yet. I'm Still new to web development

Comment: Ok. well then your first step is to go and learn AJAX. We're not able to teach you in a Stackoverflow answer.